# Incremental value of a property inside the widget tag in the ionic config.xml file.

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I add a property to the widget tag in the config.xml file in my ionic 2 cordova app? I want the value of that property to increment when ever I build the app. I want that value to be called and displayed in one of the pages in my app too.

Comment: You  will have to probably use a script to edit your config before you build though

Comment: thanks I got it sorted out. I added after_build hook. SO now the script will run after every build. I now want it to run when i give the build --prod command. How do I do that?